# Is there any option to un-flag an answer that is flagged by me?

Tags: support, flagging

I have flagged an answer ([PDF conversion on website using ASP.NET platform](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12574/pdf-conversion-on-website-using-asp-net-platform/13860#13860)) by mistake. Is there any option to un-flag it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this feature request on Meta Stack Exchange, there isn't any way to: [cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags).

I wouldn't worry about it though. Moderators evaluate each flag, and in doing so will notice things like in this case, that a recent answer to the same question was also flagged (and consequently deleted).

You always have the option of leaving a comment that can be removed by a moderator while reviewing it too.